# setState not firing inside axios POST request error handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, setstate

I am trying to set up an error handler for a React Component `SignupForm.js` that is responsible for registering users. In particular, the handler I am focused on implementing involves handling instances of a supplied user email already in use.

Here is my POST request:

```
await axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/signup", {
                name,
                email,
                password,
                tokenValue,
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("ERROR --> ", error);
                //this.displayError(error);
                this.setState(
                    {
                        err: true,
                        errcode: error.response.data.errcode,
                        errtext: error.response.data.errText,
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log("setstate done");
                    }
                );
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res !== undefined) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                }
            });
```

The image below shows Chrome Dev Tools output:

[image: print-out of the caught error object.]

As you can see, `console.log("Error --> ", error);` is indeed firing.
However, `this.setState()` doesn't seem to be firing. There are a few indications of this.

1. The `SignupForm` state, as observed using the React DevTools plugin, remains unchanged.
2. I have included a print statement at the very top of my `render()` function like so:

```
render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div className="form-container">
                <form
                    name="sign-up"
                    method="post"
                    className="form-sign-up"
```

despite the notion that `setState()` calls are supposed to trigger re-renders, the component state never gets printed to the console after the error being caught.

3. `console.log("setstate done");` never fires, as the output is also missing from the DevTools console.

### Things I have tried

1. I tried encapsulating the `setState()` call into a error handler function `displayError(e)`, like so:

```
displayError = (e) => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            err: true,
            errcode: e.response.data.errcode,
            errtext: e.response.data.errText,
        }));
    };
```

This didn't seem to have any effect. I also tried calling `displayError(e)` after having called `this.displayError = this.displayError.bind(this);` in the component constructor, which similarly had no effect.

At this point, I'm not really sure what else to try.

Comment: Can you post the entire code? Maybe on a sandbox then link it here.

Comment: First-time user of sandbox. How would I integrate an express + mysql backend? Will I have to define the DB relations from scratch?

Comment: Why you add first the `catch` before `then`?

Comment: setState? You are using a class-based component? It's a bit rare to see them nowdays, are you sure that's correct? It might help to show more code of the component. Also; your are mixing await and `.then().catch()`, which sounds very wrong

Comment: @S.Marx To be honest, I'm really not sure. Realizing now that it's odd I chose to do it that way. Could swapping the order of `then` and `catch` potentially get the `setState` call to actually work?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I will post a sandbox of the app as soon as I can. Currently trying to figure out how to get a backend up and running for that. As for your comment on using `await`, I forgot to mention that I initially *did not* have that in there. That was one of the things I experimented with. In my primitive understanding of async operations in JS, I thought perhaps await could help.

Comment: @KenLabso https://codesandbox.io/s/shoestore-signup-sheet-yixokj

Comment: @KenLabso I'm trying to figure out how to articulate a top-level `package.json` file that I can use to invoke npm scripts from `./api/package.json` and `./client/package.json` so the code can be tested and run, though I am not having much luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Initially, I was quite set on trying to get my code posted online for you folks to take a look at. After getting to know CodeSandbox a bit, I thought I was going to need to learn Docker so I could compose the front-end and back-end while having a free MySQL DB hosted somewhere online.

This was discouraging to me, as I knew Docker might take a bit of time to learn and I wanted to get to the bottom of this with the least amount of hoops possible.

I took what @S.Marx said and I investigated. After thinking about what they said a little more, it seemed strange to me as well that I would put my `catch` block before my `then` block.

Sure enough, swapping those two blocks completely solved the issue. The state is now being changed with the following:

```
await axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/signup", {
                name,
                email,
                password,
                tokenValue,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res !== undefined) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    console.log("Signup Successful!!");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Signup Error! --> ", error);
                //this.displayError(error);
                this.setState(
                    {
                        err: true,
                        errcode: error.response.data.errcode,
                        errtext: error.response.data.errText,
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log("setstate done");
                    }
                );
            });
```

Of course, now the component that is supposed to render the state change on-screen isn't showing the error message. That, however, is a separate issue.